# javaw.exe does not terminate from Task Manager upon logging out the Swing application

Tags: java, swing, process

I am launching a Swing application through JNLP on my desktop. I can see a javaw.exe process gets created under Window Task manager. Once I log out from the application which launched the Swing application, causing the swing application to close; **but** it doesn't clear the javaw.exe process from Window Task manager.

Comment: I you use `JFrame` validate that you set `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

Comment: 'Logout' isn't a term known to Java or Swing. It is an application action. What action, only you know.

Comment: in my first comment I mean "If" instead of "I" , cant change now

Comment: @MadProgrammer  That is just plain wrong.  A frame with `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` will shut down cleanly unless there are *other* non-daemon threads running.  I carefully watch all the codes I produce (all using `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`) to see the VM **does** shut down for them.  It does.

Comment: *"Thanks
Ravish"*  That is noise best left out of question bodies.  If your name is that important to you, edit [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3045236/user3045236).  BTW - do you have a question?  What is the question?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Perhaps I should have added a comment about and having non-daemon threads running ;)

Comment: The JVM will terminate when all non-daemon threads have exited or `System.exit(int)` is called. You can use `JFrame#setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` to achieve this result.  Using `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` will only allow the EDT to be terminated when the last window is closed

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

// add components to frame here

frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

From MadProgrammer :-

Swing starts a non-daemon thread known as the Event Dispatching Thread. Unless you use JFrame#setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); or System.exit, then the JVM will continue runnin

Comment: This is a reasonable solution, but it would be more helpful if you could explain why this solution is required

Comment: *"Unless you use JFrame#setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); or System.exit, then the JVM will continue runnin"*  Only if there are other non-daemon threads running.  If there *are*, it is better to discover the source of those threads and shut them down in explicitly.  For that reason I advise to use `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` and properly close the stray threads.